# Splitting the business tier in a distributed sytem into Master and Slave processes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, master-slave, distributed-system

I need to develop a Distributed system in **c# (Visual Studio)** consisting of data, business and presentation tiers . In order to do that I want to split the Business tier into master and slave processes. The master is the one containing the database and it receives updates from slave processes. Can somebody give me an idea as to how to establish this communication between the Master and slave processes and where exactly I should create the Slave object so that I can pass an instance of it to Master calling the updates from the slave?

Comment: A lot of folks use an ORM, like EntityFramework

Comment: No idea what it is but I am googling it right now

Comment: that is not the answer I am looking for..my database is a .dll file